# Flask Failed to connect, address not available

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to python and flask, I'm following this [tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/using-python-flask-and-angular-to-build-modern-apps-part-1/) to create an application with flask and angular.

To make things quicker, because I don't need a database at the moment, I skipped the steps of creating the model and the connection.

I ran this command `touch src/__init__.py` and in my `myapp/backend/src/main.py` I have this:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test')
def get_exams():
    print('ou')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000)
```

Also I created the `myapp/backend/bootstrap.sh` with this:

```
#!/bin/bash
export FLASK_APP=./src/main.py
source $(pipenv --venv)/bin/activate
flask run -h 0.0.0.0
```

But if I try to run `curl http://0.0.0.0:5000/test` I got this error `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 5000: Address not available`

Aside from the database steps, I made everything according to the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You need named the route to the method `exams` `/test`.
So you need to call /test not /exams

```
curl http://0.0.0.0:5000/test
```

The route defines the URI/URL and calls the method associated with it. The names are totally independent and completely up to you. So you are very fine to also name the route `/exams` as well.

Comment: sorry, I did try with `/test`, but I copied the command from the page when I paste it here haha